# Check whether a variable is an Array

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to find out whether a variable is an array or not

```
  if (params.writtenLines == ???)
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

More importantly, why do you want to check whether it's an array? If you know the parameter might be a single string or a list, you can now use:

```
def lines = params.list("writtenLines")
```

That came with Grails 1.2.

Answer (score 13):

This functionality is already available in pure Java and can therefore be used in Groovy, too:

```
if (params.writtenLines.class.isArray())
```

Comment: Thanks dude, 
I found this as well

if ( params.writtenLineID.getClass().isArray())


Keep up the good work cheers.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is a bit late, but what about this:

```
List.isCase(params.writtenLines)
```

Wouldn't it be a correct solution, too?